# SERIALIZABLE. Изоляция данных

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transaction

Пытаюсь разобраться с работой изоляций. Создал Spring-Boot приложение с использованием Hibernate. Мне необходимо понять как работает блокировка таблиц базы данных на время транзакции.

Для этого в приложении запускаю поочередно два потока, каждый из которых обращается к Базе данных и считывает строку из таблицы `person`. Сначала первый поток начинает транзакцию, но не завершает ее, а засыпает на 5 секунд. В это время второй поток начинает свою транзакцию и обращается к той же таблице, как я понимаю эта транзакция должна ждать когда разблокируется таблица, завершением транзакции первого потока и начнет свою. Но программа выводит следующее:

```
Sleep 5 sec... Block Table
Jonh (2)
Jonh (1)
```

Все ли я верно понимаю? Должно ли это работать? Перепробовал разные способы, но так и не получилось( Помогите

---

**Код программы**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath*:applicationContext.xml")
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>Person</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

hibernate.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Person: (слой Model)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

PersonServiceImpl (Слой Service):

```
@Service(value = "personService")
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "personDAO")
    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO= personDAO;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void myMethod() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(personDAO.getById(1).toString)+" (1)";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        // Пауза, чтобы первый поток успел обратится к таблице
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(personDAO.getById(1).toString+" (2)");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

PersonDAOImpl (слой DAO):

```
@Repository(value = "personDAO")
public class PersonDAOImplimplements PersonDAO {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory")
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    boolean firstThread = true;

    @Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public Person getById(int id) {
        Person person = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Person.class, new Integer(id));

        if(this.firstThread) {
            this.firstThread=false;

            // Останавливаем поток. Как я понимаю никто не должен получить доступ к Таблице
            System.out.println("Sleep 5 sec... Block Table");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return person;
    }
}
```

Comment: У транзакций, которые только читают данные, нет причин блокировать друг друга.

Comment: уровни изоляции - это **не** блокировки, они могут в конечном счете выражаться в блокировках, но не обязаны их запускать, они лишь обязаны выполнять набор правил.

Comment: @Etki да спасибо, я неверно понял роль изоляции, мне необходимы `LockOptions` и `LockMode`. Пытаюсь разобраться в простом примере, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать блокирование доступа к данным таблицы. Суть в том, чтобы выбранные из таблицы данные были неизменны пока не закончится вся транзакция, которая опирается на эту выборку и добавляет в эту же таблицу новую строку. Если обе транзакции выберут один и тот же набор данных, это будет приводить к ошибкам.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно мало смысла говорить о поведении конкурентных запросов на разных уровнях изоляции в отрыве от конкретной СУБД. Абстрактный уровень изоляции - это набор минимальных требований к исключению вполне конкретных аномалий. (кстати, именно минимальные требования. Например, read uncommited не позволяющий чтение незафиксированных изменений допустим). Про то, как именно этот уровень должен быть реализован в стандарте не говорится. Поэтому у каждой СУБД может быть свой подход к обеспечению этих требований.

Уровень serializable требует, чтобы результат выполнения запросов параллельно не отличался от выполнения последовательно. Два читающих запроса никак друг другу не мешают и не изменяют состояние системы. Поэтому даже если в конкретной субд уровень изоляции serializable реализован через блокировки - эксклюзивные блокировки для этого использовать крайне странно. Используются разделяемые блокировки, которые допускают параллельное чтение этой строки, но заблокируют изменение. Использование эксклюзивной блокировки для читающих запросов спровоцирует слишком резкий провал производительности конкурентных запросов без каких-то особых положительных моментов.

А может ничего не блокироваться даже при изменениях. Но штатно прилетать ошибка сериализации транзакции с требованием просто повторить транзакцию с начала.